# OS X Spotlight searching from a user-defined database?

Tags: macos, dictionary, spotlight

Since 10.5, Spotlight on Mac OS X has this nice **Dictionary integration** you might have seen:

[image: Dictionary integration in Spotlight]

Any ideas how anything like this could be implemented?

It seems that the current Dictionary+Spotlight friendship is somewhat hardcoded into Spotlight's code (for example, there is a specific user defaults key `com.apple.spotlight.DictionaryLookupEnabled` present just for toggling dictionary searching).

I've read in the [Spotlight Importer Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/MDImporters/MDImporters.html) that one can create a Spotlight importer only on a **per-document basis**, that is if your application *Foobar* opens/creates files with extension `.foo`, you can then write a Spotlight importer for indexing properties of those files.

What I need, however, is for the Spotlight to somehow **query some sort of a database** with its own query (exactly what it now does with Dictionary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible, sorry; you need to create a file per Spotlight match.  File an enhancement request.